# Using Reflection to set a static variable value before object's initialization?

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-2.0, system.reflection

Is there anyway to set the value of a static (private) variable on an object that has not been initialized? The `SetValue` method requires an instance, but I'm hoping there's a way to get around this.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For static values you can pass null for the instance parameter.

```
var type = typeof(SomeClass);
var field = type.GetField("SomeField", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
field.SetValue(null, 42);
```

Comment: +1 fascinating : what I find a little scary in this technique is : if the field in question is readonly : this code will not cause a run-time error when executed.

Comment: If the field in question is read-only, does it just do nothing?  Or does it set the value anyway?  Is this just .NET 3.5?

Comment: +1. I think for private static you need some BindingFlags as the second parameter of the GetField method. BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic

Answer (score 1):

could you create a static function that is public and use it to set your private static variable ?

Comment: I'm guessing this is against a type for which @Chance does not have source code.

Comment: Yea, I can't muck around with the source & I'm unfortunately blocked into 2.0 w/out extension methods. Thanks though!

Comment: Extension methods cannot access private data.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx