# Using variable as a name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Normally, I can save settings like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.DarkTheme = true;
```

But how can I use variable as the name?

For example:

```
string varname = "DarkTheme";
Properties.Settings.Default.{varname} = true; //This is supposed to do the same thing as the codeblock above
```

Comment: Use reflection, see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203545/using-reflection-to-set-a-static-variable-value-before-objects-initialization). :)

Comment: @CodeCaster Could also be a dup for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection)

Comment: @Outlaw you're right, `Settings.Default` returns an instance on which you can use reflection: `PropertyInfo prop = Properties.Settings.Default.GetType().GetProperty("DarkTheme", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); prop.SetValue(Properties.Settings.Default, true, null);`.